# JavaScript for Automation - Searching Calendar

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, javascript-automation, osx-yosemite-beta

In OSX Yosemite I am use the new JavaScript for Automation feature to script Calendar.  I am attempting to search a Calendar to see if there is an event that is currently occurring.

I have done this in AppleScript like so:

```
set now to current date
every event whose start date < now and end date > now
```

I notice the in AppleScript there is a specialized AppleScript 'date' object.  The event log displays like below.  Special note about the "date" modifier before the string, indicating that this is a date object and not just a string.

```
count every event whose start date < date "Monday, August 11, 2014 at 5:49:46 PM" and end date > date "Monday, August 11, 2014 at 5:49:46 PM" and allday event = false
```

I am attempting to do this in AppleScript like so:

```
workCalendar.events.whose({
    _and: [
        { startDate: {'<': now} },
        { endDate: {'>': now} }
    ]
 });
```

But any value I set for the now var gives me the following error:

```
Error -1700: Can't convert types.
```

I have tried the following values for now and all return type conversion errors:

```
calendarApp.includeStandardAdditions = true;
now = calendarApp.currentDate;

now = (new Date());

now = (new Date()).toISOString();

now = $.NSDate.date;
```

Try to figure out what type of value it could be I did this:

```
firstStartDate = workCalendar.events[0].startDate();

console.log("firstStartDate : " + firstStartDate);
console.log("firstStartDate TO : " + (typeof firstStartDate));
console.log("firstStartDate OS : " + ObjectSpecifier.classOf(firstStartDate));
```

Which results in this inside the event log:

```
/* firstStartDate : Wed Jun 18 2014 10:30:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) */
/* firstStartDate TO : object */
/* firstStartDate OS : undefined */
```

Comment: did you try now=+new Date(); to get a number ?

Comment: Same problem with now=+new Date();  It creates a typeof number, but call to calendar still returns --> Error -1700: Can't convert types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple acknowledged this is a bug - as of Yosemite Public Beta 3 this works:

```
now = (new Date());
```

And this works

```
firstStartDate = workCalendar.events[0].startDate();
```

And this works

```
    var currentApp = Application.currentApplication();
    currentApp.includeStandardAdditions = true;
    now = currentApp.currentDate();
```